# Finding Required Permutation

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algorithms, permutations

I have numbers from $1$..$n$. I want to find number of permutation from all $n!$ permutation where the numbers have following arrangement.

$L$ $G$ $L$ $G$ $L$ *or* $G$ $L$ $G$ $L$ $G$.

Where L means that the number is less than $G$.

for ex if $n$=$4$ than I want to find following permutation

$1 3 2 4$

$2 3 1 4$

$2 1 4 3$

$1 4 2 3$

$2 4 1 3$

$4 1 3 2$

$3 1 4 2$

$3 4 1 2$

$4 2 3 1$

$3 2 4 1$

Here number of such permutation is $10$. I want to generalize it for any $n$.

Comment: "Where L means that the number is less than G." Fine, but what does $G$ mean? I cannot figure out what you are asking.

Comment: it means the number can either be ni-1<ni>ni+1 or ni-1>ni<ni+1

Comment: So, each number is either bigger than both its neighbors, or smaller than both its neighbors?

Comment: yes, thats correct.

Comment: Evidently not, since you want $(32451)$.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686946/alternating-pair

Answer (score 1):

These are called alternating permutations, see http://oeis.org/A001250

Comment: sorry can you elaborate with example. The link is not much clear

Comment: I read about alternating permutation, but my question is not exactly about them

Comment: I don't see the difference between alternating permutations, and what you are asking about. Can you give an example of an alternating permutation that you don't count? or a permutation you do count that isn't alternating?

Comment: Take n=5, than 3 2 4 5 1 is not an alternating permutation but as you can see but 324 and 451 are required permutation

Comment: True, but the numbers on either side of $4$, one of them is bigger than $4$, and the other is less than $4$. So I still don't understand what permutations you want.

Comment: i want all permutation where ni-1<ni>ni+1 or ni-1>ni<ni-1. I don't care how many such pairs are in permutation. I hope its clear now. Sorry for vagueness

Comment: Do you mean that you require either $n_{i-1}<n_{i}>n_{i+1}$ or $n_{i-1}>n_{i}<n_{i+1}$ for all $2<i<n-1,$ or that you only require it for certain $i?$  If the latter, then to which $i$ does the restriction apply?  It's hard to see why 32451 is legal but 2134 is not.