# Alternating Pair

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, permutations

I want to find the number of permutations of $1,2,\ldots,N$ having exactly $k$ triples satisfying the condition that either $n_{i-1}>n_i<n_{i+1}$ or $n_{i-1}<n_i>n_{i+1}.$

For example for N=4

0 conditions matching = 2
because permutation $1234$ and $4321$ don't satisfy the given condition.

1 matching should give 12
because in following permutation only once the condition is met

`2 1 3 4
3 1 2 4
3 2 1 4
1 2 4 3
4 1 2 3
4 2 1 3
1 4 3 2
1 3 4 2
4 3 1 2
2 4 3 1
3 4 2 1
2 3 4 1`

Similarly for 2 conditions matching it should give 10 because, 10 permutations are such that exactly 2 times the conditions are met.

`1 3 2 4
2 3 1 4
2 1 4 3
1 4 2 3
2 4 1 3
4 1 3 2
3 1 4 2
3 4 1 2
4 2 3 1
3 2 4 1`

I want a formula for counting all such conditions seperately, ex for 2 conditions, 3 conditions and so on.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686703/finding-required-permutation --- where I raised a question for the author.

Comment: Is the question clear now

Comment: This question is clear. Have you clarified the other one?

Comment: i don't understand what is being asked here.

Comment: I think you mean the following: in how many permutations of $123\ldots N$ are there exactly $k$ triples that satisfy either $n_{i-1}<n_i>n_{i+1}$ or $n_{i-1}>n_i<n_{i+1}?$  Please let me know whether this is correct, and if so, please modify the original post accordingly.

Comment: Yes i mean that. Pls help

Comment: I'll edit the post for you.

Comment: Do you know how to solve it? I was looking for some formula to help me

Comment: I don't have a good idea at the moment.  Have you looked at the link in Gerry Myerson's answer?  That sequence is, indeed, the answer to your question.  A sequence with $k+1$ alternating runs will have $k$ triples satisfying your condition.  Clearly for $k=0$ there are two permutations.  For $k=1$, the number is $2^N-4.$  This is not that hard to see.  I'm not sure whether one can expect a closed form for general $k$.  Gerry Myerson's link only gives a recurrence and an exponential generating function.

Comment: For $k=2,$ the number is $\frac{1}{2}\left(3^N-2^{N+2}-2N+11\right).$

Comment: How did you come up for k=2

Comment: I got the formula for $k=2$ essentially by curve fitting: I guessed that the leading term would be $C\cdot3^N$ and found by looking at the values for the first few $N$ that $C$ was apparently $1/2$.  After subtracting, it was easy to recognize the rest.  A proper derivation is found by expanding the exponential generating function given in the OEIS link to order $t^3$, and then writing the coefficient of $t^3$ in terms of the exponential functions $e^x$, $e^{2x}$, and $e^{3x}$.  The formula is then the coefficient of $x^N$, which is easy to get from the series for $e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like these are the numbers tabulated [here](https://oeis.org/A059427). Some recurrences are given, but no closed form formula. For example,

$P(n, k)=0$ if $n\lt2$ or $k\lt1$ or $k\ge n$;

$P(2, 1)=2$;

$P(n, k)=kP(n-1, k)+2P(n-1, k-1)+(n-k)P(n-1, k-2)$.